# Cleaning up stopped threads

Tags: java, spring, state

I have a state machine, which is used by many threads to manage the states of a game. I need to be able to clean the threads if something happens and an instance of a game does not change state for whatever reason.

How could i do this, i have the state machine?

Comment: What do you mean by "*clean the threads*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting you properly you mean to terminate threads given an event and check out if a state doesn't change. You could do it in a number of ways. Let me suggest you a possible solution.

1 - A simple way to terminate your threads would be to put those threads in a list, array, etc. a way to identify what threads you want to terminate.

2 - Create a method that terminateTheadList(...).

3 - To terminate them a way to do it would be to use the java.lang.Thread .interrupt() method. Iterate over your Thread list, array,etc. and interrupt() them. Then once you get the exception allow the thread to terminate.(that is to say, do not catch this exception and loop).

4 - To check you if the instance of the game create a new thread (this one should not be in your thread terminate list) that checks out that instance game and puts the last time this changed. Sleeps and checks out again. if the instance haven't changed call your terminateThreadList method again.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thats what i was thinking, something like mark and sweep. cheers.